# CSS class hidden-xx don't works on the boundary width value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a form using responsive design using Bootstrap. My goal is to make such input that would be the **slider** type on mobile devices, and the **text** type on medium devices and bigger.

For that reason I'm using different classes in two divs to show and hide content depending on the device screen width (e.g. hidden-xs, hidden-sm, hidden-md, hidden-lg).

```
<div class="form-group hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <!-- input type slider for mobile devices  -->
</div>

<div class="form-group hidden-xs">
    <!-- input type text for wider screen devices  -->
</div>
```

I also have a `@media` rule in my css file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sm-view {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .lg-view {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It works as I expected, except on the boundary width value of **`767px`**, on this width *both divs are visible*:

[image]

As only I increase the width value to `768px` the slider hides, and when I set the width value to `766px` the input field hides.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD** Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rnurxbw9/1/

Here the window width would be different, but you can see it on the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: I added the fiddle, please look it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not letting us know which Bootstrap version you're using. I would look at their documentation [v4 documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) or [v3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

If you're using bootstrap you shouldn't need to set any css manually. Try adding the `visible-sm` class to the one you're trying to show on larger devices.

```
<div class="form-group hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
<!-- input type slider for mobile devices  -->
</div>

<div class="form-group hidden-xs visible-sm">
<!-- input type text for wider screen devices  -->
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7-1 Bootstrap version.

Comment: Did you try removing the css you created and adding the `visible-sm` class?  Bootstrap should take care of all the css for you for responsiveness.

Comment: Yes I tried to do it, but the result is the same. Please wait I'll add the working example.

Comment: Looking at the fiddle it's only showing one `div` at the time.

Comment: Could you try with Chrome development tools, and change width by one pixel near its boundary value?

Comment: @DimaSan I actually removed all your added css and it's still working using all the default bootstrap css.

Comment: Wow! You are right, it really works without my custom CSS. Thanks :)

Comment: @DimaSan Great news, happy coding :)